# Using NSThread in this code piece

Tags: iphone, ios, nsthread

I am working on someone else's code. I came across a line of code

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

I have 2 questions to ask.

1. Its just calling a method. Why is NSThread used here?
2. While running the code, On some instances, this method doesn't get  called. When I put a breakpoint inside the method, it always get called. But if I remove the breakpoint, on some instances the method doesn't get called. Is this the problem of NSThread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using NSThread in this way means that the method "myMethod" is being called on a background thread, concurrently with the rest of the code. It is equivalent to this, which you may also have seen:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil];
```

If the method is not getting called (or seeming to not get called), it may be down to concurrency issues, i.e. the fact that the execution order of that method and ones you call after in on the main thread is not guaranteed, so you are expecting it to be called earlier than it actually is.

If you say:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(methodA) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
[self methodB];
```

Then methodA and methodB will be running *at the same time* and there is no guarantee that methodA will finish before methodB.

Answer (score 2):

I always use `NSThread detachNewThreadSelector` in combination with an auto-release pool, like so:

```objc
  -(void)myMethod {
      NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];
      // .. Do stuff in this thread
      [pool release];
  };
```

If you want to "simply" perform a selector, do it like this:

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod)];
```

Comment: That's also good advice, although these days you should use @autoreleasepool { ... } instead.

Comment: If you use ARC `@autoreleasepool` blocks are the way to go, else either way is okay: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html. `@autorelease` blocks are more (code) efficient.

Comment: @autoreleasepool blocks are actually more performant as well - they eliminate the creation of an additional object and several objective-C method calls. They aren't just syntax sugar as they might seem.